# Downloading Ngrok on Mac

Tags: ngrok

So i downloaded Ngrok on my windows machine it was pretty straight forward unzipping and running.

Now I want to run it on my mac I am faced with all sorts of problems.

I downloaded Ngrok from ngrok.com

However it doesn't seem to download as a zip file?

This is where my Ngrok is kept

/Users/Jay/Downloads

What do i have to type in my terminal in order to get this to work? It doesn't seem to be zipped as mentioned.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When using ngrok on Mac, be sure you're running the command from the directory where the ngrok binary resides.

So for your installation, you downloaded ngrok to `/Users/Jay/Downloads`, so the binary is probably in a directory called `/Users/Jay/Downloads/ngrok/bin`.

You can use `./ngrok help` to test that this works.

So the command to try this from a terminal might look like this:
`./Users/Jay/Downloads/ngrok/bin/ngrok help`

Or cd directly into that `/bin` directory and try `./ngrok help` from there.

Note that the initial period/full-stop ("`.`") is needed.

Also, do yourself a favor by adding it to your root directory so you can just call the command from a new shell with just `./ngrok help`.